# Discarding alpha channel from images stored as Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, math

I load images with numpy/scikit. I know that all images are 200x200 pixels.

When the images are loaded, I notice some have an alpha channel, and therefore have shape (200, 200, 4) instead of (200, 200, 3) which I expect.

Is there a way to delete that last value, discarding the alpha channel and get all images to a nice (200, 200, 3) shape?

Comment: Assuming, you are using `Image.open(<image_path>)` you can discard the alpha value by doing `Image.open(<image_path>).convert('RGB')`. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Just slice the array to get the first three entries of the last dimension:

```
image_without_alpha = image[:,:,:3]
```

Comment: I think this will reduce the quality of the image?

Comment: @AleksandarJovanovic do you precisely know what you mean by "quality of the image"? Dropping alpha removes information about transparency of pixels but does not influence other information (e.g., color).

Answer (score 4):

scikit-image builtin:

```py
from skimage.color import rgba2rgb
from skimage import data
img_rgba = data.logo()
img_rgb = rgba2rgb(img_rgba)
```

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/transforming_image_data.html#conversion-from-rgba-to-rgb-removing-alpha-channel-through-alpha-blending
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#rgba2rgb

Answer (score 2):

Use `PIL.Image` to remove the alpha channel

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("c:\>path_to_image")
img = img.convert("RGB") # remove alpha
image_array = np.asarray(img) # converting image to numpy array
print(image_array.shape)
img.show()
```

If images are in `numpy` array to convert the array to `Image` use `Image.fromarray` to convert array to `Image`

```
pilImage = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need higher speed, you can use cvtColor in cv2 (openCV):

```py
img_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img_RGBA, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
```

It took 1/4 time of numpy slice method.